# SQL Server : How can I enable/reconfigure xp_cmdshell through a linked server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xp-cmdshell

So I want to enable xp_cmdshell through a linked server.
This is my attempt:

```
set @execute = 'exec '+'['+@server_ip+']'+'.master..sp_configure ''xp_cmdshell'', 1;'
set @reconfigure = 'exec '+'['+@server_ip+']'+ 'reconfigure'

exec sp_executesql @execute
exec sp_executesql @reconfigure
```

I have to run the reconfigure command, as I receive this message:

'Configuration option 'xp_cmdshell' changed from 0 to 1. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install.'

The reconfigure part does not work. I don't know how to activate the reconfigure command through a linked server. Thanks!

Comment: What does *doesn't work* mean? Do you get an error? Why are you trying to enable a dangerous feature like `xp_cmdshell` remotely instead of asking the server's DBA to do it on the server? If you lack such permissions, you won't be able to enable it in any way

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos : well, I want to do a stored procedure which works with xp_cmdshell on different servers, and I want to make sure xp_cmdshell is turned on (on the respective server) when the procedure runs. I don't want to do that manually every time locally.

Comment: Yes I get error, could not find stored procedure '[server_ip]' ...

Comment: and it is not duplicate, I already saw that post before and it does not refer to linked servers.

Comment: This means you have a typo on the second command, which produces `exec [10.10.10.10]reconfigure`.

Comment: Could not find stored procedure '10.10.10.10'. It would have been nice to work :)

Comment: It's still a typo. You are trying to execute a command as if it were a stored procedure. You can't write `exec [10.10.10.10]reconfigure` or `exec [10.10.10.10] reconfigure` or `exec [10.10.10.10].reconfigure`. Try to create an `exec` statement that works first, then try to use the ip as a parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo on the second command, which produces `exec [10.10.10.10]reconfigure`. This is the wrong way to execute a command though. `RECONFIGURE` is a command just like `EXEC`, so you can't call it the same way you call a stored procedure

To execute a command on a linked server you need to use the `EXEC ... AT linked_server_name` [syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(EXEC_TSQL);k(SQL12.SWB.TSQLRESULTS.F1);k(SQL12.SWB.TSQLQUERY.F1);k(MISCELLANEOUSFILESPROJECT);k(DevLang-TSQL)&rd=true):

```
EXEC ('RECONFIGURE') AT my_server_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you put them in the same session?

```
set @execute = 'exec '+'['+@server_ip+']'+'.master..sp_configure ''xp_cmdshell'', 1; exec '+'['+@server_ip+']'+ 'reconfigure'

exec sp_executesql @execute
```

Comment: good point! :), for optimization